# Как спарсить подчёрнкутые данные

Tags: python, парсер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
по гет запросам в json их нету. Чтобы получить к ним доступ в таблице нужно нажать на статистику

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите пример. Например, ссылку на страницу. То, что уже сделали (будет от чего отталкиваться тем, что захочет помочь)

Comment: А так, посмотрите в сетях какой запрос отправляется при клике на статистику (мб и не будет отправки запроса, тогда нужные данные уже загружены, но это маловероятно)

Comment: по post запросам, по cookies?